# How do I get amsrefs to include the publisher’s name in a cross-reference?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, amsrefs

I have the following example for doing cross-referencing using the `amsrefs` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Please see \cite{B} for more details.

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
  \bib*{A}{book}{
    title = {Proceedings of the 10th Annual International Conference on XXX},
    publisher = {La-La},
    date = {2000}
  }
  \bib{B}{article}{
    title = {A Brief History of XXX},
    author = {John, M.},
    xref = {A},
    date = {2000},
    pages = {70--80}
  }
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

Running this through LaTeX and previewing the PDF document, I find that the article’s entry in the bibliography contains the title of the conference-proceedings book but not the name of the book’s publisher. Is there an elegant way of fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the specs for a `collection.article`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\BibSpec{collection.article}{%
    +{}  {\PrintAuthors}                {author}
    +{,} { \textit}                     {title}
    +{.} { }                            {part}
    +{:} { \textit}                     {subtitle}
    +{,} { \PrintContributions}         {contribution}
    +{,} { \PrintConference}            {conference}
    +{}  {\PrintBook}                   {book}
    +{,} { }                            {booktitle}
    +{,} { }                            {publisher}
    +{,} { \PrintDateB}                 {date}
    +{,} { pp.~}                        {pages}
    +{,} { }                            {status}
    +{,} { \PrintDOI}                   {doi}
    +{,} { available at \eprint}        {eprint}
    +{}  { \parenthesize}               {language}
    +{}  { \PrintTranslation}           {translation}
    +{;} { \PrintReprint}               {reprint}
    +{.} { }                            {note}
    +{.} {}                             {transition}
    +{}  {\SentenceSpace \PrintReviews} {review}
}


\begin{document}

Please see \cite{B} for more details.

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
  \bib*{A}{book}{
    title = {Proceedings of the 10th Annual International Conference on XXX},
    publisher = {La-La},
    date = {2000}
  }
  \bib{B}{collection.article}{
    title = {A Brief History of XXX},
    author = {John, M.},
    xref = {A},
    date = {2000},
    pages = {70--80}
  }
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

In `amsrefs.sty` the publisher is not included in the information for that entry type. Note that it's better to classify it `collection.article` rather than `article` anyway.

[image]

Comment: Hi egreg. I have a further question. How would I add the editor field for `amsrefs`? I require something like “Name of book, Editor 1 and Editor 2 (Eds.), ...” I don’t know how to add “(Eds.)” using `\BibSpec`.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore That's too much for a comment, it's better to open a new question on the site.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Section 8.3 of the [package documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf), compound fields can also function as cross-reference fields. In this case, you can get the publisher's name to appear by using `book={A}` instead of `xref={A}`.

[image: Screenshot of the output when book={A} is used instead of xref={A}]

Here, the year `2000` appears twice because the entry `date={2000}` occurs in the `\bib*{A}{book}` entry and also separately in the `\bib{B}{article}` entry. Sometimes, this could indeed be the required behaviour; but, in this case it seems to be redundant, so you can remove the `date` entry in the `\bib{B}{article}` entry.

---

To be fair, the [documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) is a bit unclear about when `\xref` should be used instead of a compound field like `book` for cross-referencing, literally leaving it as "an exercise for the reader" [section 8.3, page 24].

A little experimentation with the examples provided in the documentation provides the following rules of thumb:

1. `\xref` behaves as if all the fields in the `\bib*` cross-reference are added verbatim to the main `\bib` reference, except for any `title` field, which is added as a `booktitle`. For instance, in your MCVE, the output contains the title of the article as well as the title of the conference, since the latter field is imported as a `booktitle` field by `xref`:

   > M. John, *A Brief History of XXX*, Proceedings of the 10th Annual International Conference on XXX, 2000, pp. 70–80.
2. Any fields that are duplicated by the cross-reference are ignored. This is the case with the `date` field in your MCVE: notice that the year "2000" occurs only once in the output, as it should.
3. Any fields in the cross-reference that are not recognized by the main `\bib` reference type are simply ignored. In your case, the fields `publisher` and `address` added by the cross-reference are being ignored because these fields are not recognized by the `article` entry type.
4. When using a compound field, say `book`, for cross-referencing, the fields in the `\bib*` cross-reference are imported verbatim inside the `book` compound field in the main `\bib` reference. Any field that this "innerbook" field (in this case) recognizes is printed, and any field that it does not recognize is ignored.