# How do I use amsrefs to enter editors’ names in the standard format?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, amsrefs

I have a question about `amsrefs` that is in addition to the one that I already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210776/how-do-i-get-amsrefs-to-include-the-publisher-s-name-in-a-cross-reference) and that was answered. I would like to know how to enter editors’ names using `amsrefs`.

Specifically, I would like to have the following format:

> Name of article’s author, title of article, title of conference proceedings book in which the article appears, **name of first editor** and **name of second editor** (Eds.), name of publisher, address of publisher, year of publication, page numbers.

I know that using `\BibSpec`, I have some control over information fields:

```
\BibSpec{collection.article}{%
  +{}  {\PrintAuthors}                {author}
  +{,} { \textit}                     {title}
  +{.} { }                            {part}
  +{:} { \textit}                     {subtitle}
  +{,} { \PrintContributions}         {contribution}
  +{,} { \PrintConference}            {conference}
  +{}  {\PrintBook}                   {book}
  +{,} { }                            {booktitle}
  +{,} { }                            {publisher}
  +{,} { \PrintDateB}                 {date}
  +{,} { pp.~}                        {pages}
  +{,} { }                            {status}
  +{,} { \PrintDOI}                   {doi}
  +{,} { available at \eprint}        {eprint}
  +{}  { \parenthesize}               {language}
  +{}  { \PrintTranslation}           {translation}
  +{;} { \PrintReprint}               {reprint}
  +{.} { }                            {note}
  +{.} {}                             {transition}
  +{}  {\SentenceSpace \PrintReviews} {review}
}
```

However, due to the lack of online references, I do not know how to use `\BibSpec` to display editors’ names as indicated above, especially how to include the phrase “(Eds.)” without making it appear twice if I have to enter the names of two editors.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the full technical documentation for `amsrefs` is now linked from
[this page](http://www.ams.org/authors/tex/amsrefs).  it is also present in a
full tex live distribution, although to get at it, it's necessary to ask for
`texdoc -l amsrefs` and select `amsrefs.pdf`, because the first choice for
`texdoc` is usually the user documentation (`amsrdoc.pdf` in this case).

in the list of commands shown for the package, there are three for editors:

- `\PrintEditorsA` -- prints the names followed by "(ed.)" or "(eds.)"
- `\PrintEditorsB` -- puts parentheses around the entire list of editors
- `\PrintEditorsC` -- precedes the editors' names by "Edited by"

`\PrintEditorsA` looks like the appropriate choice for this situation.

If the `\BibSpec` as shown in the question otherwise produces the desired output,
then the appropriate place to insert the editors would be this:

```
+{,} { }                            {booktitle}
+{,} { \PrintEditorsA}              {editors}
+{,} { }                            {publisher}
```

(this is untested, so if something is slightly out of kilter, please feel free to
correct it.)